# Is it normal for opengl to lower image quality?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to make an old game look a bit better, it uses opengl version 1.1, as you can see, this in a comparison between how the image looks on photoshop vs how it looks ingame.

[image]

As you can see on the right (ingame) the borders are blurry, not as sharp as the original image. (Please ignore all the text).

Is this expected because of the old version of opengl? Or is it something that could be fixed?

Comment: Are you drawing at integer coordinates or at positions that are not quite exactly ints?

Comment: Coordinates are exactly ints

Comment: If the answer below worked, it means that your cooddinates are not exactly ints.

Comment: I thought he meant coordinates as in the position where I was displaying the image on screen. Position are x/y ints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have some sort of filtering enabled on your texture. Look for `GL_LINEAR` in your code and replace it with `GL_NEAREST`

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texBuff);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```